# How to include libsqlite3 in my Haxe/hxcpp build?

Tags: c++, haxe, hxcpp

I have a very simple test put together to include SQLite3 in my Haxe build (I know it has SQLite built in, but this issue doesn't just apply here). It looks like so:

```
@:include("sqlite3.h")
@:buildXml('<files id="haxe" append="true"><compilerflag value="-lsqlite3"/></files>')
extern class SQLite3 {
    @:native("sqlite3_open") public static function sqlite3_open(path: String, outReference:Reference<DBPointer>):Int;
}

@:include("sqlite3.h")
@:native("sqlite3")
extern class DBPointer {

}
```

This doesn't throw any Haxe errors, but when I try to compile, I get the following error in C++ compilation:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_sqlite3_open", referenced from:
    Main_obj::main() in aea44ed0_Main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I had figured that adding the `buildXml` instructions you can see there would be enough to dynamically reference the macOS SQLite library, but it seems that is not the case.

How can I go about including SQLite here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [hxcpp build XML documentation](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/hxcpp/blob/master/docs/build_xml/Linker.md), I believe you should replace

```
<compilerflag value="-lsqlite3"/>
```

with

```
<flag value="-lsqlite3"/>
```

or

```
<lib base="sqlite3"/>
```

Comment: Been trying to find exactly this kind of documentation forever! Thank you very much.

Comment: Happy to help, @Alastair! I can also recommend that you check Hugh Sanderson's talks on past WWXs ([2015](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hltXpZ3Upxg), [2016](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1yuMSS5nR4g)) or [this year's Haxe Summit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mTsr38FaMW0).  This year's workshop on writing C++ externs was also [recorded](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p4kw2QSaSi8).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a lot about using CPP external libraries (so this doesn't precisely answer your question), but I do know that an SQLLite implementation is built into Haxe (for the cpp, hl, java, lua, macro, neko, php, and python platforms.) Here're some related documentation:

- https://api.haxe.org/sys/db/Sqlite.html
- https://api.haxe.org/sys/db/Connection.html
- https://api.haxe.org/sys/db/ResultSet.html

Here's a snippet (from this [full example gist](https://gist.github.com/jcward/a2bc21576cba2587bba1d18b647c0f7d).)

```
var conn = sys.db.Sqlite.open("test.db");

var rs = conn.request('
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS artists_backup
  (
    artistid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name NVARCHAR
  );
');

var rs = conn.request('INSERT INTO artists_backup (name) VALUES ("John");');
```

Note that a `ResultSet` is an `Iterator<Dynamic>`, but you can put in a type hint to keep your DB code nice and type-safe:

```
typedef RecordType = { name:String, id:Int };

for (record in (rs:Iterator<RecordType>)) {
  // While record is still a Dynamic object, the TypeDef alias tells
  // the compiler that .name and .id are the only valid fields.
}
```

Comment: I know this is old, but: `sys.db.Sqlite` isn't very good --- no parameterised queries and no prepared statements, which is error-prone and kills performance. I'm having to roll my own for that reason.

Comment: Here it is: https://github.com/davidgiven/stellation/blob/stellation7/src/runtime/cpp/Sqlite.hx